# Bitbucket docker pipeline inside another docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to setup **bitbucket** pipeline to run protractor tests. Setup is bit complex we are using docker to run the pipe line setup(**pipeline.yml** file) and inside that we are using other docker image to deploy,test and notify. I wont able to replicate this issue on local environment but just want to know is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple steps in your yml file and specify the images you are pulling. You can have multiple images in one yml file. You can share the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file for more clarification and assistance.